# How do you say in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

this is a stand alone sentence. I want to be able to translate it from English to Latin. I've tried google translate and a couple of other sites but I keep getting conflicting translations. I especially would like the correct word for regret which keeps translating to sorry which changes the nuance of the sentence from feeling regret over an action missed to an apology. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me :)

Comment: Sorry if I'm being slow, but what is the sentence you are trying to translate? The question does not seem to contain anything to be translated. If this is in reference to [your earlier question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17099/79), please edit that post (there's a button under that post for doing so) to add details there.

Comment: I am trying to get the correct translation from English to Latin of the sentence: "I regret not telling you I love you."

Comment: My apologies! I'm new here and didn't realize the question wasn't showing in the heading and I did not repeat it in the body

Comment: Thanks! So this is indeed an improvement on the previous question you asked. I included this as an edit there and reformatted a bit. I'll mark this one as a duplicate. You can always edit that question further!